# inexplicable crash fixed by superfluous assignment

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I was testing a tiny snippet I'd written to format a timespan (e.g., `last change 5m23s ago`) and kept getting an error I couldn't understand. Every time I try to use the loop variable `i` directly in a call to `ts()`, ASP informed me `An error occurred...`

```
'the function
function ts(s)
    dim m: m = CLng(s \ 60): s = s mod 60
    dim h: h = CLng(m \ 60): m = m mod 60
    ts = right("00" & h, 2) & "h" & _
         right("00" & m, 2) & "m" & _
         right("00" & s, 2) & "s" 
end function 

'the test
for i = 0 to 90000 step 15 
   '               response.write i & ": " & ts(i) & "<br />" 'an error has occurred
    dim j: j = i : response.write i & ": " & ts(j) & "<br />" 'works fine
next
```

What in the world is going on here?

Why does `ts(i)` create an error every time?
Given that, why does `j=i : ts(j)` work fine?

It can't be a problem with the variable `i`, since it works fine with the write call. Here's some other things I tried:

```
response.write i & ": "                     'no problem
'response.write ts(i)                       'crashes
'dim x: x = ts(i)                           'crashes
dim j: j = i                                'no problem
dim x: x = ts(j)                            'works
response.write x & "<br />"                 'works 
'response.write ts(j) & "<br />"            'also works 
'response.write i & ": " & ts(j) & "<br />" 'also works
```

(Finally, I know there's allegedly a way to make IIS display real errors. I'd love to hear how to do that without RDP access to the webserver.)

Comment: Try to change `function ts(s)` to `function ts(ByVal s)`

Comment: That worked. SO ANGRY. `function ts(sec) : dim s: s = sec` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[omegastripes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2165759/omegastripes) clued me in.

Apparently in VBScript, the default is for parameters to be passed `ByRef`erence.
(Literally every other programming language I've ever used passes primitives `ByVal`ue)

This caused a problem when I changed the value of `s` inside the function.

Any of these snippets work just fine:

```
function ts(ByVal s)
    ...
...
ts(i)

function ts(sec)
    dim s: s = sec
    ...
...
ts(i)
```

(or, as mentioned in the OP, passing the value in a non-loop-iterator variable)

```
function ts(s) 
... 
dim j: j = i: ts(j)
```